# How to add and use Arabic dictionary translation for theorem, example,

Tags: beamer, babel, arabic, translator

With  beamer babel translate strings like Figure, Table, Table of Contents, ....  more strings like theorem, example, definition, ..... are translated with `translator` package for some languages. but Arabic language isn't supported with `translator`. how can I add translation of those strings in Arabic?

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\today\par 
\contentsname\par 
\figurename\par

\hrulefill

% strings non translated

%
\sectionname\par 
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
\end{example}

\begin{corollary}
\end{corollary}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My aim is to use `translator` package, I have created Arabic dictionaries

```
translator-months-dictionary-Arabic.dict
translator-theorem-dictionary-Arabic.dict
translator-numbers-dictionary-Arabic.dict
translator-basic-dictionary-Arabic.dict
translator-bibliography-dictionary-Arabic.dict
translator-environment-dictionary-Arabic.dict
```

For example contents of `translator-numbers-dictionary-Arabic.dict` file

```
\ProvidesDictionary{translator-numbers-dictionary}{Arabic}

\providetranslation{one}{واحد}
\providetranslation{two}{اثنان}
\providetranslation{three}{ثلاثة}
\providetranslation{four}{أربعة}
\providetranslation{five}{خمسة}
\providetranslation{six}{ستة}
\providetranslation{seven}{سبعة}
\providetranslation{eight}{ثمانية}
\providetranslation{nine}{تسعة}
\providetranslation{ten}{عشرة}
\providetranslation{eleven}{احدى عشرة}
\providetranslation{twelve}{اثنى عشرة}

\providetranslation{One}{واحد}
\providetranslation{Two}{اثنان}
\providetranslation{Three}{ثلاثة}
\providetranslation{Four}{أربعة}
\providetranslation{Five}{خمسة}
\providetranslation{Six}{ستة}
\providetranslation{Seven}{سبعة}
\providetranslation{Eight}{ثمانية}
\providetranslation{Nine}{تسعة}
\providetranslation{Ten}{عشرة}
\providetranslation{Eleven}{احدى عشرة}
\providetranslation{Twelve}{اثنى عشرة}

\providetranslation{first}{الأول}
\providetranslation{second}{الثاني}
\providetranslation{third}{الثالث}
\providetranslation{fourth}{الرابع}
\providetranslation{fifth}{الخامس}
\providetranslation{sixth}{السادس}
\providetranslation{seventh}{السابع}
\providetranslation{eighth}{الثامن}
\providetranslation{ninth}{التاسع}
\providetranslation{tenth}{العاشر}
\providetranslation{eleventh}{الحادي عشر}
\providetranslation{twelfth}{الثاني عشر}

\providetranslation{1st}{1.}
\providetranslation{2nd}{2.}
\providetranslation{3rd}{3.}
\providetranslation{4th}{4.}
\providetranslation{5th}{5.}
\providetranslation{6th}{6.}
\providetranslation{7th}{7.}
\providetranslation{8th}{8.}
\providetranslation{9th}{9.}
\providetranslation{10th}{10.}
\providetranslation{11th}{11.}
\providetranslation{12th}{12.}
```

Then  I have inserted this line to `translator.sty` to add Arabic option

```
\DeclareOption{arabic}        {\trans@use@and@alias{arabic}    {Arabic}}
```

And I try with this example which does not give the desired result

```
% lualatex
\PassOptionsToPackage{arabic}{translator}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{theorem}

\end{theorem}

\translate[to=Arabic]{one}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## **Update**

@Davislor I still face some issues, for just one language Arabic I need to insert `\languagepath{Arabic}` but with two languages the last code cause the  translation for second language to appears also in Arabic

```
% lualatex
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,nil]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\uselanguage{Arabic}
%\languagepath{Arabic}

% This way translation for Spanish is ok but there is no
% translation for theorem in Arabic !
% If we incomment \languagepath{Arabic} translation for 
% Arabic is ok but with Spanish translation of therem appears in Arabic !
   
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{theorem}

\end{theorem}

\translate[to=Arabic]{one}

\selectlanguage{spanish}

\begin{theorem}

\end{theorem}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## *Without \languagepath{Arabic}*

[image]

## *With \languagepath{Arabic}*

[image]

Comment: You would want to define theorem styles that have Arabic names, in either `ntheorem` or `amsthm`.

Comment: @Davislor my aim is to add arabic translation like with french or spanish  just like this 
`\documentclass[Arabic]{beamer}`

Comment: Added a new answer that should work for you.

Comment: My answer did correctly select the language for the template I provided, but you wanted the dictionaries to follow the same naming convention as `translator` (so, `Arabic` instead of `arabic`). I’ve revised my answer to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already created the dictionaries `translator-theorem-dictionary-Arabic.dict`, etc., in some directory your TeX engine searches, you need to add the line

```
\uselanguage{Arabic}
```

to your preamble, and `translator`, which `beamer` loads, will use them.  If you want to follow the naming convention of the `translator` package, but also have `translator` select Arabic when the current `\languagename` is `arabic`, also add the command

```
\languagealias{arabic}{Arabic}
```

I used your numbers dictionary and the following dummy `translate-theorem-dictionary-Arabic.dict`.  I did not even attempt to translate Arabic sttings, since you say you’ve done that already, but put in placeholders to verify that `translator` is using the right dictionary.

```
\ProvidesDictionary{translator-theorem-dictionary}{Arabic}

\providetranslation{Comments}{Comments in Arabic}
\providetranslation{comments}{comments in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Comment}{Comment in Arabic}
\providetranslation{comment}{comment in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Corollaries}{Corollaries in Arabic}
\providetranslation{corollaries}{corollaries in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Corollary}{Corollary in Arabic}
\providetranslation{corollary}{corollary in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Definitions}{Definitions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{definitions}{definitions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Definition}{Definition in Arabic}
\providetranslation{definition}{definition in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Examples}{Examples in Arabic}
\providetranslation{examples}{examples in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Example}{Example in Arabic}
\providetranslation{example}{example in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Exercises}{Exercises in Arabic}
\providetranslation{exercises}{exercises in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Exercise}{Exercise in Arabic}
\providetranslation{exercise}{exercise in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Facts}{Facts in Arabic}
\providetranslation{facts}{facts in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Fact}{Fact in Arabic}
\providetranslation{fact}{fact in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Key Lemmas}{Key Lemmas in Arabic}
\providetranslation{key lemmas}{key lemmas in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Key Lemma}{Key Lemma in Arabic}
\providetranslation{key lemma}{key lemma in Arabiv}
\providetranslation{Key Observations}{Key Observations in Arabic}
\providetranslation{key observations}{key observations in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Key Observation}{Key Observation in Arabic}
\providetranslation{key observation}{key observation in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Lemmas}{Lemmas in Arabic}
\providetranslation{lemmas}{lemmas in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Lemma}{Lemma in Arabic}
\providetranslation{lemma}{lemma in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Main Theorems}{Main Theorems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{main theorems}{main theorems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Main Theorem}{Main Theorem in Arabic}
\providetranslation{main theorem}{main theorem in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Observations}{Observations in Arabic}
\providetranslation{observations}{observations in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Observation}{Observation in Arabic}
\providetranslation{observation}{observation in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Problems}{Problems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{problems}{problems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Problem}{Problem in Arabic}
\providetranslation{problem}{problem in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proofs}{Proofs in Arabic}
\providetranslation{proofs}{proofs in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proof}{Proof in Arabic}
\providetranslation{proof}{proof in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proof Sketch}{Proof Sketch in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proof sketch}{Proof sketch in Arabic}
\providetranslation{proof sketch}{proof sketch in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proof Sketches}{Proof Sketches in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proof sketches}{Proof sketches in Arabic}
\providetranslation{proof sketches}{proof sketches in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Sketch of Proof}{Sketch of Proof in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Sketch of Proofs}{Sketch of Proofs in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Sketch of proof}{Sketch of proof in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Sketch of proofs}{Sketch of proofs in Arabic}
\providetranslation{sketch of proof}{sketch of proof in Arabic}
\providetranslation{sketch of proofs}{sketch of proofs in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Propositions}{Propositions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{propositions}{propositions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Proposition}{Proposition in Arabic}
\providetranslation{proposition}{proposition in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Remarks}{Remarks in Arabic}
\providetranslation{remarks}{remarks in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Remark}{Remark in Arabic}
\providetranslation{remark}{remark in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Solutions}{Solutions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{solutions}{solutions in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Solution}{Solution in Arabic}
\providetranslation{solution}{solution in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Theorems}{Theorems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{theorems}{theorems in Arabic}
\providetranslation{Theorem}{Theorem in Arabic}
\providetranslation{theorem}{theorem in Arabic}
```

This, plus the example `translator-numbers-dictionary.Arabic.dict` that you provided, is enough to compile the following MWE:

```
% lualatex
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if using a character not in the current font.
\documentclass[professionalfonts,unicode,spanish,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning,nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%% You seem to want these commands activated by passing translator the
%% [arabic] or [Arabic] options.  You can give the latter to `\documentclass`
%% without activating an obsolete, incompatible .ini file in babel.
\uselanguage{Arabic}
\languagealias{arabic}{Arabic}

\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\newenvironment{spanish}%
  {\begin{otherlanguage}{spanish}}%
  {\end{otherlanguage}}
\babeltags{Arabic=arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary},Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Amiri}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}{ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\today\par 
\figurename\par
\contentsname\par

\hrulefill

% strings non translated
 
\tableofcontents
\section{A Section}
 
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
\end{example}

\begin{corollary}
\end{corollary}

\begin{definition}
\end{definition}

\begin{spanish}
\begin{theorem}
El primer teorema (\textArabic{\upshape\translate{one}}) en castellano.
\end{theorem}
\end{spanish}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Amiri/Libertinus font sample]

You seem to want to modify the `translator` package itself to run the two necessary commands if you give it the `[arabic]` option.  For the time being, you would be stuck using `\PassOptionsToPackage{arabic}{translator}` before `\documentclass{beamer}`, since for the moment you cannot pass `[arabic]` to the document class without passing it to `babel`, which loads an obsolete 8-bit `.ldf` file and breaks.  You could work around this by supporting `\usepackage[Arabic]{translator}`.

I note in passing that the basic design of `translator` is inadequate for translating even phrases such as “the first theorem.”  It assumes you can translate English into other languages simply by word substitution.  That breaks even for Spanish grammar, where `\translate{first}` would give you “primero” and there is no way to generate ”primera,” “primer,” “segunda,” etc.  It’s even more unsuitable for German, where the correct translation of “first” in context might be “erste”, “erster”, “erstem”, “ersten”, or “erstes”.

#### Original Answer

You can define new theorem environments with `amsthm` (and its Beamer extensions), similar to the ones Beamer provides for German.

```
% lualatex
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning,nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Arabic}
\babelfont{tt}{ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\babeltags{ar=arabic}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{arthm}{\textar{Translation of Theorem}}[section]
\newtheorem*{arcor}{\textar{Translation of Corollary}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ardefn}{\textar{Translation of Definition}}[section]
\newtheorem{arexmpl}{\textar{Translation of Example}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\today\par 
\figurename\par
\contentsname\par

\hrulefill

% strings non translated
 
\tableofcontents
\section{A Section}
 
\begin{arthm}
\end{arthm}

\begin{arexmpl}
\end{arexmpl}

\begin{arcor}
\end{arcor}

\begin{ardefn}
\end{ardefn}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There isn’t a `\sectionname` in the standard classes, and Beamer doesn’t display one.  However, you could provide a translation of a caption Babel supports, such as`\arabicchaptername` or `\chaptername`, or redefine the header format.

If you want to write a new package, you probably want to take advantage of `translator` dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks Davislor,  still some issues in case of two languages.

Comment: @SalimBou Can you be more specific?

Comment: See the update of my question.