# Pass "arabic" option to translator and not to babel

Tags: beamer, macros, arabic, documentclass-writing, class-options

This question is a complement of [How to add and use Arabic dictionary translation for theorem, example,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555251/54817)

I have a class `beamer-rl` based on `beamer` to create presentation for right to left languages, here are the first lines of it

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-rl}
[2019/10/04 v1.3 LaTeX class to patch beamer for right to left presentation with babel]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=beamer-rl,
    prefix=beamer-rl@,
    setkeys=\kvsetkeys,
}

% babel options:
\define@key{beamer-rl}{babel}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}%
}

\DeclareVoidOption{arab}{%
            \PassOptionsToPackage{arabic}{translator}%
}

\DeclareDefaultOption{%
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}%
}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\else
\ClassError{beamer-rl}{beamer-rl require luatex}
\fi

\LoadClass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
```

I need to write `doocumentclass[arabic]{beamer-rl}` to pass option `arabic` to package translator   without passing it to babel  which break with an obsolete 8-bit .ldf file.

I used instead `arab` option but I  was hoping to use  `arabic` option to maintain the same format for calling language in beamer.

So my question is how to define `arabic` option without passing it to `babel` package?

Comment: Easiest way: don't setup a class option for this, but if the user needs it, let him use `\PassOptionsToPackage` directly. If that's not viable, everything else doesn't seem like a clean interface. The class options are explicitly global options in LaTeX which can apply to any package. What you could do (but I'd never do this), is define your `arabic` option such that it removes `arabic` from the global option list.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz and how to do that?

Comment: You really shouldn't do that, how is a user supposed to set options globally if a class starts to deliberately remove options from the global list?

Comment: @SalimBou That's an interesting question, which can also affect many other ‘complex’ languages with lots of tricks for they to work in 8-bit engines. It's clearly a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, the following should remove a single option from the list of global options. Again, I really recommend to not use this!

```
\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement\CurrentOption\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist
```

Both `\@expandtwoargs` and `\@removeelement` are contained in the LaTeX2e kernel.

Comment: Thanks, this work fine I changed the declation of option like this 
`\DeclareVoidOption{arabic}{%
\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement\CurrentOption\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist 
 \PassOptionsToPackage{arabic}{translator}%
}`